# Typescript. Are Triple-Slash references still required when using "import from"

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

In old versions of Typescript it was required to add the famous

```
/// <reference
```

label to add the required references. Now after version **1.6** we can import dependencies using the recommended ES6 way

```
import Greeter from "./greeter";
```

I have been reading for a while but it is still not clear to me whether and why the triple-slash references must be completely avoided or not.

BTW. Will now the compiler know in which order it has to compile the TS files if we are using `filesGlob` instead of `files` in the tsconfig.json?

Comment: If you want to write es6/amd/commonjs modules - you will use import. If you want to have single file project - you can use namespaces and reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, I don't believe `filesGlob` is officially supported yet: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1927

Now as far as the triple slash reference, it is not required as long *as everything is referenced in `files` in tsconfig.json*.

You'll find that if you use a tool like `tsd` or `typings` to manage type definitions for your external libraries, they will create a single file that you include in tsconfig.json; that single file *will use* triple slash references to include the rest of the files.

You can find more information about triple slash references in the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

Comment: The point is that filesGlob generates automatically a files clause. But this doesn't seem to have the proper order. I will take a look at the issue you mention. Anyway what you say about typings is not really true, the actual .d.ts files don't have any triple-slash reference and I don't have to reference that single file where those references are listed

Comment: In the files section though, you only need to include your entry point.  The TypeScript comiler will automatically generate the correct order starting from the entry point, and following your imports; Anything that defines globals and is not imported elsewhere is a different case.

Comment: Note that this is only correct using imports and external modules. If you are using namespaces/internal modules, the compiler will not order them correctly - you'll have to order them yourself in *files* or use triple-slash references.

Answer (score 3):

When using internal modules/namespaces we need the `///<reference` in order to tell the compiler what depends on what in order to build a dependency graph and sort the files in the right order.

The ES6 way that you describe are (external) modules, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242. As such, the ordering for concatenation is not relevant as these are loaded asynchronously.

So using ES6 modules, you do not need `///<references`.

As for [fileGlobs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1927), this is not implemented in TypeScript (yet), but even when it is, I think it's unlikely that it will change anything about the dependency resolution of the files in the project. Even in [atom-typescript](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript) where they implement fileGlobs, they are very [opinionated against](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md) code that "depends on any form of js ordering" and they don't support in any other way than manually ordering the files in tsconfig.json.

Comment: So if you're using a node internal like Buffer, you still need triple-slash references?

Comment: @DarkNeuron Do you mean that you want to pull in a npm package and use it in TypeScript code? Then it's a external module and you should load it using `import`. Then you won't need the triple-slash references.