# typescript export imporatble from tsd

Tags: typescript, tsd, swagger-codegen

File `index.ts` *(generated with swagger-codegen)*

```
export * from './api/api';
export * from './model/models';
```

---

File `tsd.d.ts`

```
...
/// <reference path="path/to/index.ts" />
```

---

`typescript 2.2.1.`

**Why do I still need to use import statements** (`import myDTO from 'path/to/file/myDTO'`) in my `ts` files? 
Am I missing a concept, should a module be declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in index.ts you have export statements - this make it an [external module](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html). In order to consume external module - you must import it.

Some more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502078/typescript-are-triple-slash-references-still-required-when-using-import-from) on [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) [matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684802/when-do-i-need-a-triple-slash-reference).

Comment: A sub question, if you don't mind. Can I use import statements without generated JS code having "defined", "require" or other module mechanisms? I'm asking this, because writing angular1 factories with TS and can't get around generated code with modules management.

Comment: I am afraid that it is not possible. Even if you will use `outFile` + AMD/system module (see --module in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) the transpiler will still wrap the resulting single file with corresponding functions.